# add unique file names to for loop file downloader

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm using a for-loop to request files from an API. I'd like to name each file using a list of names (image_list).

```
for i in download_url_list:
response = requests.get(i, stream=True)
with open('/Users/Zack/Downloads/' + ??? +  '.zip', "wb") as handle:
    for data in tqdm(response.iter_content()):
        handle.write(data)
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also please don't post your code as an image.

Comment: Please put the code in text in a code block. This will help with search and people helping by copy/pasting...

Comment: It's helpful if you post actual code, rather than a screenshot - that would normally be reserved for evidence of the expected input or output. You also don't indicate how it is that your code is failing and where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mapping (dict) between urls and filenames, and then iterate over the dictionary.

Another way is to `zip` two lists and iterate over the result.

Yet another way is to enumerate the urls and get a filename based on the index.

The first option assumes no duplicates in `download_url_lists`
Last two assume `download_url_lists` and `image_list` have the same size.

```
info = zip(download_url_lists, image_list)
for url, filename in info:
    ...

# or
mapping = dict(info)
for url, filename in mapping.iteritems():
    ...

# or 
for index, url in enumerate(download_url_lists):
    filename = image_list[index]
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! I used your third suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable which changes in every iteration;

See this:-

```
>>> list1 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
>>> 
>>> var, list2 = 0, []
>>> for i in list1:
...     filename = 'file{}'.format(var)
...     var += 1
...     list2.append(filename)
... 
>>> list2
['file0', 'file1', 'file2', 'file3']
```